# Swift - multiple unitsStyles in DateComponentsFormatter?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I'm trying to find a way to use Swift's [`DateComponentsFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter) with multiple [`unitsStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter/1413441-unitsstyle) properties, depending on the actual component.

For example, I'd like to use `.abbreviated` for the day property and `.brief` for others, creating strings such as: `1d 9hr 22min`. If I used `.brief` for all components, I'd get `1day 9hr 22min`. If I used `.abbreviated`, I'd get `1d 9h 22m`.

It looks like the combination I want isn't possible, because `unitsStyle` is a property of the formatter. But does anyone know if I can make a more complex configuration? Or am I going to have to create multiple `DateComponentsFormatter`s?

(I want to use `DateComponentsFormatter` to get the localisation of the time units. So any alternative formatters would also need to support localisation out of the box, rather than having localised formatting strings.)

Comment: Two formatter, one for day and one for hour and minutes with different styles and then you merge the strings yourself into one

Comment: @JoakimDanielson for English that should be easy but if OP wants to support different languages that's not so simple

Comment: @LeoDabus You mean because the order might be different? I didn't consider that and yes it is a workaround/hack either way.